# Proving by induction

Tags: algorithms, induction, trees

I'm having a problem relating to **proving by induction that the Preorder(T) and Postorder(T) algorithms both print out all the nodes in the tree without repetition.**

I'm not quite sure where to start..

Any help would be much appreciated :)

**Preorder(T) algorithm**

> 1. Print the root $r$.
> 2. If $r$ has children then let $x_0,\dots,x_n$ be all the children of $r$, in left-to-right order.
> 3. Set $T_i$ to be the subtree whose root is $x_i$ for $i = 0,\dots,n$.
> 4. While $i\le n$ do $\text{preorder}(T_i)$.

**Postorder(T) algorithm**

> 1. Set $c = r$.
> 2. If $c$ has children then let $x_0,\dots,x_n$ be all the children of $c$ in the left-to-right order.
> 3. Set $T_i$ to be the subtree whose root is $x_i$ for $i = 0,\dots,n$.
> 4. While $i\le n$ do $\text{postorder}(T_i)$.
> 5. Print $c$.

Comment: If you want a specific proof, you should describe the algorithms exactly (or give reference to exact descriptions)...

Comment: oops my apologies, I thought it was a very general algorithm. I'll add it now

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by strong induction on the height of the tree.  A tree of zero height has one node-you should be able to show that it prints that node and stops.  Then assume all trees of height $\le n$ are printed correctly.  Given a tree of height $n+1$, when you call the other preorders they do not include the root, so it will not be repeated, and they will be printed correctly.